Improving CNN Performance with a Parallel Neural Network for Dynamic Weight Assignment
I'm trying to improve my regression model, a Convolutional Neural Network, by assigning a weight between 0-1 to all datapoints, which in turn tells me how good a specific datapoint is at making a prediction. The point is that some datapoints are noisy and make worse predictions, I want these to have lower weights so that they're ignored in the end and during training.
What I've done: Tried implementing a parallel neural network (nn) that outputs a weight between 0 and 1, and assigns this weight to the associated datapoint/image.
Both networks receive the same datapoint as an input, and the nn outputs a weight, while the regression cnn outputs a value Y_i. The results are then concatenated and passed on to the mutual custom loss function for both networks, that multiplies the squared difference between the predicted value and target value with the given weight from the parallel nn: sum((Y(:,i)-T(:,i))^2)*W(i).
The problem is that the model seems to converge towards smaller weights W(i) since this will minimize the loss, how can I fix this?
I've tried adding regularization term proportional to the magnitude of the weight to penalize small weights. It helped but the results are still not near as good as without the parallel nn.
#functional api
inputs = Input(shape=(16,150,1) )


x2 = Conv2D(64, 3, 1, activation='relu', data_format="channels_last", name='Conv1')(inputs)

x2 = MaxPooling2D()(x2)
x2 = BatchNormalization()(x2)



x2 = Conv2D(74, 2, activation='relu')(x2)
x2 = MaxPooling2D()(x2)
x2 = BatchNormalization()(x2)

x2 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu')(x2)
x2 = Flatten()(x2)


x2 = Dense(256, activation='relu', name="FC1")(x2)
x2 = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='FC2')(x2)
regression_output = Dense(1, name='Output')(x2)

# Weight NN 
x1 = Flatten()(inputs) # same inputs as for CNN above
x1 = Dense(64, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01))(x1)
x1 = Dense(64, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01))(x1)
x1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x1)

weight_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='weight_output')(x1)  # Weight as an output
weight_output = tf.maximum(weight_output, 0.1)  # Ensure weights are at least 0.1
combined_output = Concatenate()([regression_output, weight_output])
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=combined_output)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    regression = y_pred[:, 0]
    weight = y_pred[:, 1]
    # L2 penalty on weights as before
    #weight_penalty = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(weight))
    #l1_penalty = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(weight))  # L1 penalty
    #lambda_l1 = 0.10  # Regularization strength for L1
    return tf.reduce_mean(weight * tf.square(y_true - regression))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss, metrics = ['mae'])


I've now added the code.

What do you mean "while the regression cnn outputs one value", don't they both output a scalar? What you are doing makes no sense, I don't understand your motivation. If I have a loss function L := L(x_1, ..., x_N) * w, w=0 will always trivially minimize the loss.

Yes both outputs a scalar. The weights here are not to be confused with the weights in the layers of the networks. The weights are to be assigned to each datapoint in the dataset, for when later making a prediction, I want to look over a certain interval of datapoints and make a sampled prediction based on the datapoints with the highest weights. The point is that some datapoints are noisy and make worse predictions, I want these to have lower weights so that they're ignored in the end.

if the question uses the same term weights for two different meanings, then it should explicitly say so in the question. Otherwise, how would a reader know this ?

Look at what you wrote: sum((Y(:,i)-T(:,i))^2)*W(i) your parenthesis are off, this shows w * L not \sum_i L_i w_i.  Ignoring that since I think I get what you're saying, nothing has changed. There is no objective for optimizing w. Functionally, making it zero will always be the best outcome. You can get a nonzero result by imposing a lower bound on w, such as L -> L + L_w ~ 1 / ||w||. Still, I don't think this will achieve your ultimate objective though
